# When I login the system, authorized is working but after I login, I run a another request but its not give me response cause of unauthorized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I post a login informations to my server and getting authorized, but after I login I get the client information with another request, its not working. I thought its about the cookies but not sure. If its about cookies how can I get the cookies and the set it inside of 'GET' client request ?

I've tired to add `credentials: "include"`and the other options of credentials but did not work. I saw a package which is `react-native-cookies` but I could not implement it into my functions.

This is my Login Request :

```
export const postUserLogin = (email, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        fetch('http://1xx.xx.xx.xx/login', {
            credentials: "include",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        })
            .then(res => {
                res.json()
                    .then(jres => {
                        resolve(jres);
                    }).catch(e => {
                        reject(e);
                    })
            }).catch(e => {
                reject(e);
            })
    }
    catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }

})
```

And this is my getClient Information Request :

```
export const getClient = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {

        fetch('http://1xx.xx.xx.xx/',  {
            credentials: "include",
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
            },
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            res.json()
                .then(jres => {
                    resolve(jres);
                }).catch(e => {
                    reject(e);
                })
        }).catch(e => {
            reject(e);
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }

})
```

Comment: You might need to send Authorized headers in getClient() request which causes you to unauthorized. You should check your required params in service